# Handelling the website interface using UIWebview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an website, which i want to display it in UIWebView. but the website have an interface options as `standard, basic` and `mobile`, but the default is standard, can i change this default in to mobile, if so how can i do it.

please find the image below for better understanding
[image]

kindly let me know. if i can change the interface in to mobile as default in UIWebView .

Comment: where you facing problem? identifying client as iOS OR to change default selection?

Comment: to change default selection

Comment: Are you using jQuery or javascript?